# Connection string Database First approach Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, connection-string

I need someone to help me with this.

I have a project developed in ASP.NET MVC. I am using database first approach. I have around 40 databases in my model. The problem I have is the following. I already did coding for two databases by calling like this in controller:

```
db1Entities image = new db1Entities();
var update = image.App_Details(Convert.ToInt32(primarykey)).ToList();
```

But now I need to call this for 40 different databases. All these databases have same tables and stored procedures. I need to select connection string based on name which I have in front end.

If I have to do this inside controller, then I need to put 40 different conditions every time and call above code like :

```
if(name == "test1")
{
    db1Entities image = new db1Entities();
    var update = image.App_Details(Convert.ToInt32(primarykey)).ToList();
}

if(name == "test2")
{
    db2Entities image = new db2Entities();
    var update = image.App_Details(Convert.ToInt32(primarykey)).ToList();
}
```

and so on. I don't want to do this for every controller. So what I am thinking about is I could do this in separate class by comparing with names and assign to image like:

```
if (name == "test1")
{
    db1Entities image = new db1Entities();              
}

if(name == "test2")
{
    db2Entities image = new db2Entities();              
}
```

and after this I should be able to pass this image and connect database in controller like :

```
   var update = image.App_Details(Convert.ToInt32(primarykey)).ToList();
```

Please can someone help me in achieving this?

Comment: Do databases differ? You can create one context which fits all databases. Then the only thing is left is to set correct connection string for each case.

Comment: @voroninp results of database differes but table names are same. can you explain me in detail what I am supposed to do? I am new to this.

Comment: You created the model from one database. You can edit the model in the designer and leave only the tables you really need. If schema of the tables absolutely the same as in other databases then you can use this only model to connect to other databases without recreating  models for every database. Just give your DbEntities correct connections string. By default EF uses connections string from the config file but you can set it programmatically.